Functional trace in Schwinger effect
I'm reading this review about the Cosmological Schwinger effect by Jérôme Martin and I have a doubt computing the following functional trace
\begin{align}
|\langle 0^-|0^+\rangle|^2=&\det\left(\frac{1}{1+e^{-\pi\Upsilon}}\right)=\exp\left[-\text{Tr}\ln\left(1+e^{-\pi\Upsilon}\right)\right]\\=&\exp\left[-\frac{VT}{(2\pi)^3}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2}(qE)^2~\exp\left(-\frac{n\pi m^2}{qE}\right)\right],
\end{align}
with $\Upsilon=(k_\perp^2+m^2)/(qE)$ and $k_\perp^2=k_x^2+k_y^2$, so the trace has to do with the momentum space, but I'm not really sure how to compute it. My attempt is the following
\begin{align}
\text{Tr}\ln\left(1+e^{-\pi\Upsilon}\right)&=\text{Tr}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\exp\left(-\frac{n\pi m^2}{qE}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{n\pi k_\perp^2}{qE}\right)\\&=N\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\exp\left(-\frac{n\pi m^2}{qE}\right)\int d^2k_\perp\exp\left(-\frac{n\pi k_\perp^2}{qE}\right),
\end{align}
where $N$ hides my lack of knowledge on how to compute the functional trace. The last integral gives
\begin{align}
\int d^2k_\perp\exp\left(-\frac{n\pi k_\perp^2}{qE}\right)=2\pi\int_0^\infty d|k_\perp|\,|k_\perp|\exp\left(-\frac{n\pi |k_\perp|^2}{qE}\right)=\frac{qE}{n}
\end{align}
so there is a factor $qE$ missing.
I've seen in Section 5.4 of Parker and Toms that $qE$ is also squared in their computation of Schwinger effect.
My question is how to compute the Trace so the other $qE$ factor shows up.

Is the integration over k not perhaps 3 dimensional?

@flippiefanus The integral over $k_z$ might be included in the $N$, since the argument of the trace does not depend on $k_z$.  However, I don't see how it would give another $qE$ factor.
